# ERROR: Constructing component 'objective' from data=None failed: TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: pyomo

Team Pyomo,
I kindly need help with the above-stated error. I have done everything I could, but still can't get my model to work. Below is the formulation of my 'Objective Function', and screenshots of the errors message. Thank you.

[image]

Screenshot of the error from the running code at the command prompt:
[image]

Comment: `f = 1234.5; f[6]` <-- that's the crux of the problem. So *why* is there a float where it is not expected?

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your feedback, however, I do not have your referenced info, f[6] and f = 1234.5; in my code and/or error file. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you add in how you declared `m.d` and `m.x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `model.x` and `model.d` are declared correctly with 2-D indices, the problem is that you are using double square brackets. The correct way to access a particular index is `model.x[i,j]`.

Here are the correct ways to declare `model.x`, `model.d`, and `model.a`.

Assuming `model.a` is two dimensional:

```
model.a = Set(initialize=[(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)])
model.d = Param(model.a, default=0)
model.x = Var(model.a)

def _obj_rule(m):
    return sum(m.d[i,j]*m.x[i,j] for i,j in m.a)
model.obj = Objective(rule=_obj_rule)
```

Assuming `model.a` is one dimensional:

```
model.a = Set(initialize=[1,2,3])
model.d = Param(model.a,model.a,default=0)
model.x = Param(model.a,model.a)

def _obj_rule(m):
    return sum(m.d[i,j]*m.x[i,j] for i in m.a for j in m.a)
model.obj = Objective(rule=_obj_rule)
```

Notice that either `model.a` is declared as two dimensional or `model.x` and `model.d` are indexed by `model.a` twice. Also notice the slight differences in how the sum in the objective is written.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications and the illustration. However, I did try that approach, but it did not work. I have also cross-checked the declaration of my model.d and model.x; they both seem to be correctly done per examples in the Pyomo book. For instance model.d = Param (model.I, model.J) and, model.x = Var(model.I, model.J). Could you please give me an example of the 2-D indices form if my version is incorrect. Thank you.

Comment: Could you show more of your model implementation in the question? Are `model.d` and `model.x` both doubly indexed by `model.A`? Are you now seeing a different error message after switching from the double square brackets?